# Finding the co-efficient of $x^{10}$ in $\frac{1}{(1-x^{10})(1-x^5)(1-x^2)(1-x)}$

Tags: recreational-mathematics

While trying to solve a problem with from STEP questions, I encountered this. I am not sure whether this approach is right for that question but this doesn't look like the right way to approach. Any information would be helpful.

Comment: what is "this" approach? perhaps you meant to have a hyperlink?

Comment: What is the denominator in 1/(1-x^10)(1-x^5)(1-x^2)(1-x)?

Comment: Use $\frac{1}{1-y} = 1 + y + y^2 + y^3+....$ and then just count who will give you the required index.

Comment: @A.G. 1 is the numerator and the rest is in the denominator. Thanks

Comment: @Shailesh sorry

Comment: @Shailesh you should probably make that into an answer.

Comment: What I did was multiplied the denominator and raise it to the power of (-1).

Comment: Sorry @Shailesh can u explain your method clearly please .

Comment: Will wait. If no one posts an answer within a day, I will.

Comment: While we wait for Shailesh to find the time you can study generatingfunctionology and some examples such as [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/25430/11619), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/89240/11619) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/339692/11619). Plenty of other good examples.

Comment: [This](https://oeis.org/A000008) is also something that might be interesting in connection with this question. Maybe that coin problem is the origin?

Comment: So will the binomial expansion work if I just substitute a negative number ?

Comment: I read one of the results proved bu Euler.

Comment: It is that there are as many distinct ways of writing the power n as the sum of postive while numbers as there are using odd whole numbers .